# E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred. Object does not exist at location., ANYONE CAN SORT IT OUT?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin

I am working on the application , which have Register activity(having email, password &confirm password fields) using Firebase , then next activity is profile Completion activity (having name, age, mobile No, and Upload Image field). I am getting error while uploading image into firebase as mentioned in Title,also data (name,age,mobileNo) is not going as my code uploads the image first, i really don't know why it's happening,

```
package com.example.application.activity

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.example.application.R
import android.app.Dialog
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
import android.net.Uri
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.view.Window
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Gallery
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.application.user_student_data_class
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.firestore.ktx.firestore
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage
import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
import java.util.*

private lateinit var etName: EditText
private lateinit var etAge: EditText
private lateinit var etMobileNo: EditText
private lateinit var btnChooseImage: Button
private lateinit var btnSave:Button

private lateinit var ivProfileImage:CircleImageView

private lateinit var imageUri: Uri


private lateinit var dialog: Dialog

class ProfileCompletionActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_completion)

        etName = findViewById(R.id.etName)
        etAge = findViewById(R.id.etAge)
        etMobileNo = findViewById(R.id.etMobileNo)
        btnChooseImage = findViewById(R.id.btnSelectImage)
        btnSave = findViewById(R.id.saveBtn)
        ivProfileImage = findViewById(R.id.ivProfilePic)



        btnChooseImage.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
            intent.type = "image/*"
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
        }

        btnSave.setOnClickListener {
            saveProfileData()
        }

    }

    private fun saveProfileData() {
        val name = etName.text.toString().trim()
        val age = etAge.text.toString().trim()
        val mobileNo = etMobileNo.text.toString().trim()

        if (name.isEmpty() || age.isEmpty() || mobileNo.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter all the details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return
        }

        if (!::imageUri.isInitialized) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please select an image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return
        }

        val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        if (user == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "User not logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return
        }

        val filename = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        val ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("user_student/")
            .child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment()!!)


        ref.putFile(imageUri)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                ref.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { it ->
                    val profileData = user_student_data_class(name, age, mobileNo, it.toString())
                    val db = Firebase.firestore
                    db.collection("user_student")
                        .document(user.uid)
                        .set(profileData)
                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Profile data saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            finish()
                        }
                        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Error saving profile data: ${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error uploading image: ${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            imageUri = data.data!!
            val bitmap= MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, imageUri)

            ivProfileImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
            ivProfileImage.alpha= 0f
        }
    }

    private fun showProgressBar(){
        dialog= Dialog(this@ProfileCompletionActivity)
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_wait)
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
        dialog.show()
    }

    private fun hideProgressBar(){
        dialog.dismiss()
    }

}
```

Firebase Rules of Firestore

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

whatever i tried, i am only getting this line of error(in title).[as you can see firebase console having all paths using in the code but made by me manually :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjA8t.png)

Comment: If you try to log `imageUri.getLastPathSegment()` what do you get printed out?

Comment: `Image URI: content://com.miui.gallery.open/raw/%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FPictures%2FIMG_20230405_192909.jpg`         `Last path segment: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG_20230405_192909.jpg` @AlexMamo

Comment: its from inside SaveProfileData(), `Image URI.Last Path SEGMENT: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/IMG_20230405_192909.jpg`

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose).